# Filesystem Case-Sensitivity Mismatch (Android Studio & IntelliJIDEA) on OSX 10.10.1

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, android-studio, filesystems, case-sensitive

I am getting the **Filesystem Case-Sensitivity Mismatch** warning in Android Studio (and IntelliJIDEA CE14).
So I clicked [this link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Filesystem+Case-Sensitivity+Mismatch), which was recommended by the IDE and did as **Wessel van Norel** says but the warning still does appear.

Is that because I added the required line `idea.case.sensitive.fs=true` to just the copy as suggested by Mr. van Norel?

How can I solve this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I "solved" the problem. In fact it was kind of my own stupidity (sorry for that!).

Previously I added the `idea.properties` file to the **AndroidStudio**- and **AndroidStudioBeta**-directories.

I did not do the same for **AndroidStudioPreview1.2** because I thought that it is not a preview anymore (Android Studio > About Android Studio says it is Beta) but since I started using AS while it was still a preview-version it seems to be the right directory.

(I checked for IntelliJIDEA and there is no warning.)

Answer (score 1):

If Android Studio is installed using `brew install Caskroom/cask/android-studio`, the `idea.properties` file is located at `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/android-studio/2.0.0.20_143.2739321/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties`